# SSIS Best Practice - Do 1 of 2 dozen things

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that is processing a queue. 
I currently have a singel package that is broken into 3 containers
1. gather some meta data
2. do the work
3. re-examine meta data, update the queue w/ what we think happened (success of flavor of failure )

I am not super happy with the speed, part of it is that I am running on a hamster powered server, but that is out of my control.

The middle piece may offer an opportunity for an improvement...
There are 20 tables that may need to be updated. 
Each queue item will update 1 table. 
I currently have a sequence that contains 20 sequence containers.

They all do essentially the same thing, but I couldnt figure out a way to abstract them.

The first box in each is an empty script action. There is a conditional flow to 'the guts' if there is a match on tablename.

So I open up  20 sequence tasks, 20 empty script tasks and do 20 T/F checks.

Watching the yellow/green light show, this seems to be slow.

Is there a more efficient way?  The only way I can think to make it better is to have the 20 empty scripts outside the sequence containers. What that would save is opening the container. I cant believe that is all that expensive to open a sequence container. Does it possibly reverify every task in the container every time?

Just fishing, if anyone has any thoughts I would be very happy to hear them.

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue right now is that you are running this in BIDS.  This is designed to make development and debugging of packages easy, so yes to your point it validates all of the objects as it runs.  Plus, the "yellow/green light show" is more overhead to show you what is happening in the package as it runs.  You will get much better performance when you run it with DTSExec or as part of a scheduled task from Sql server.  Are you logging your packages?  If so, run from the server and look at the logs to verify how long the process actually takes on the server.  If it is still taking too long at that point, then you can implement some of @registered user 's ideas.

Comment: I appreciate that point. Things do run faster on the server. Its not the magnitudes of increase I would like, but its a relatively weak VM server (I dont get to be involved in the server setup...).

Answer (score 1):

Are you running each of the tasks in parallel?  If it has to cycle through all 60 objects serially, then your major room for improvement is running each of these in parallel.  If you are trying to parallelize the processes, then you could do a few solutions:

1. Create all 60 objects, each chains of 3 objects.  This is labor intensive to setup, but it is the easiest to troubleshoot and allows you to customize it when necessary.  Obviously this does not abstract away anything!
2. Create a parent package and a child package.  The child package would contain the structure of what you want to execute.  The parent package contains 20 Execute Package tasks.  This is similar to 1, but it offers the advantage that you only have one set of code to maintain for the 3-task sequence container.  This likely means you will move to a table-driven metadata model.  This works well in SSIS with the CozyRoc Data Flow Plus task if you are transferring data from one server to another.  If you are doing everything on the same server, then you're really probably organizing stored procedure executions which would be easy to do with this model.
3. Create a package that uses the CozyRoc Parallel Task and Data Flow Plus.  This can allow you to encapsulate all the logic in one package and execute all of them in parallel.  **WARNING** I tried this approach in SQL Server 2008 R2 with great success.  However, when SQL Server 2012 was released, the CozyRoc Parallel Task did not behave the way it did in previous versions for me due to some under the cover changes in SSIS.  I logged this as a bug with CozyRoc, but as best as I know this issue has not been resolved (as of 4/1/2013).  Also, this model may abstract away too much of the ETL and make initial loads and troubleshooting individual table loads in the future more difficult.

Personally, I use solution 1 since any of my team members can implement this code successfully.  Metadata driven solutions are sexy, but much harder to code correctly.

Comment: - thanks for the suggestions. The 20 sequences are all parallel within the parent sequence container.    

I have considered sub packages before but i seem to be reconnecting to the database upon executing a sub package. I have a previous post where I tried to investigate that problem.  I was unsucessful and that led to my current monolith. (its great for parties at the summer solstice...bring your club...)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest wrapping your 20 updates in a single stored procedure. Not knowing how variable your input data is, I don't know how suitable this is, but this is my first reaction.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The quandry I find myself in, and the whole reason I have to use SSIS, is this...  the source data is in oracle and we dont have a linked server, so putting it all in a single SP isnt an option, unless Im missing something....

Comment: So your target (tables to be updated) are Oracle and your source is something else? In that case, no you can't use an SP. Increasing server size is unlikely to make a difference either. I don't quite understand what your'e doing, but are you updating large tables? You'll need to isolate the performance issue more thoroughly - i.e. is it the UPDATE, the scripts, the database? Anyway you have an answer so good luck.

Answer (score 1):

well - here is what I did....

I added a dummy task at the 'top' of the parent sequence container. From that I added 20 flow links to each of the child sequence containers (CSC). Now each CSC gets opened only if necessary.

My throughput did increase by about 30% (26 rpm--> 34 rpm on minimal sampling).

I could go w/ either zmans answer or registeredUsers. Both were helpful. I choose zmans because the real answer always starts with looking at the log to see exactly how long something takes (green/yellow is not real reliable in my experience).

thanks